# Using Python and NLP to get the most frequent POS tag from a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I'm trying to get the most frequent POS tags (top five) from a list.

```
pos_list = nltk.pos_tag(list)
#pos_list = [('caught', 'NN'), ('black', 'NN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('striped', 'JJ'), ('eel', 'NN')]
tag_fd = nltk.FreqDist(tag for (word, tag) in pos_list)
```

I've also tried looping through `pos_list` to count the tags that way but there seems like there has to be a way to do this using `NLTK`.  I've also tried to create a string out of the list and trying the same approach but that isn't working either.

```
str_of_list = " ".join(list)
tag_fd = nltk.FreqDist(tag for (word, tag) in str_of_list)
```

Thanks any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this from within NLTK, but `collections.Counter` certainly has a way:

```
import collections

pos_list = nltk.pos_tag(list)
pos_counts = collections.Counter((subl[1] for subl in pos_list))
print "the five most common tags are", pos_counts.most_common(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

An equivalent method to the one presented by @inspectorG4dget which remains within NLTK (i.e. without using collections) is using `nltk.FreqDist` as follows:

```
pos_list = nltk.pos_tag(list)
pos_counts = nltk.FreqDist(tag for (word, tag) in pos_list)
print "the five most common tags are", pos_counts.most_common(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import nltk
from collections import Counter
text='apple is a good company'
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(text.split())
print(Counter(i[1] for i in tagged).most_common(2))



output ->[('NN', 2), ('VBZ', 1)]
```